# Proof of Khintchine inequality

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, functional-inequalities

I'm trying to go through a proof of Khintchine inequality, available 
[here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiH45qGpt_JAhXHWhoKHWz_AwMQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstudents.mimuw.edu.pl%2F~lk234151%2Fworks%2Fchinczyn.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH2g_17DTYI5zOpxF6-tGmpTPfukg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.d2s):  sadly only a polish version available, but perhaps language will not be a barrier here. I understand everything perfectly up to the third line on page 5, where we make a jump from

$||S||_{L^p}^{1-s}||S||^s_{L^3}\\$

to

$3^{6(1/p - 1/2)}||S||_{L^p}$ ,

where $S:= \sum_{k=1}^n x_k r_k$

and at this point I am completely lost. Where on earth is this bound coming from? Is it only true because we deal with Radamacher variables defines as functions $r_i$ of the form of $t \mapsto sgn(sin(2i\pi t))$ or does it hold in general for functions in $L^p$ spaces? I thought it was just some sort of a trick but after a considerable time of playing with exponents etc. I still do not have any clue as to why this might be true.

PS. If you struggle with the language, I'm quite happy to translate the details, but I suppose it is understandable (I might a bit biased on that one though since I actually know the language :) ). Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the argument is the following. Thanks to the "$p=3$" case, you have
$$\Vert S\Vert_3\leq \sqrt{C_3}\, \Vert S\Vert_2\,.$$

This gives you
$$\Vert S\Vert_2\leq \Vert S\Vert_p^{1-s}\times C_3^{s/2}\Vert S\Vert_2^s\, ;$$
in other words 
$$\Vert S\Vert_2^{1-s}\leq C_3^{s/2}\, \Vert S\Vert_p^{1-s}.$$
So you obtain
$$\Vert S\Vert_2\leq C_3^{s/2(1-s)}\, \Vert S\Vert_p= C_3^{3(\frac1p-\frac12)} \,\Vert S\Vert_p\,,$$
because, as it turns out (and if I didn't make any mistake) $\frac{s}{1-s}=6\bigl(\frac1p-\frac12\bigr)$.

Now, apparently $C_3\leq 2\times 3-1=5$; so what you get in the end seems to be
$$\Vert S\Vert_p\leq 5^{3\bigl(\frac1p-\frac12\bigr)}\,\Vert S\Vert_2\, .$$

This is not exactly what is given in the notes. Quite possibly, I made some mistake somewhere; but anyway, the method (*i.e.* to use the "$p=3$" case) is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks very much for claryfing, I do understand it now. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome!